# Using Git clone in Google Colab and using a csv file

Tags: google-colaboratory

I am using a github project on Google Colab. I used the !git clone to clone the repository. But then I am unable to read a csv file using pd.read_csv. What am I doing wrong? Thanks.

Comment: Can you provide more details? What are the exact commands that you've been using, what's the error message?

Answer (score 2):

Are you prepending the git repository directory in your call to `pd.read_csv`? `!git clone` will clone the repo, but it won't change the current directory. You'll need to use `%cd` to change directories.

So, for example, if you clone `!git clone foo.git`, which contains a file called `csv`, you'll want to do something like:

```
!git clone foo.git
%cd foo
pd.read_csv('csv')
```

Comment: Thank you. I was using !cd instead of %cd.

Answer (score 0):

you can try like this

```
%cd '/content/drive/My Drive/' #point to destination directory
!git clone 'https://github.com/Recommenders' #copying from github into the destination directory
```